# Reducing $\binom{t-2}{n-2}/\binom{t-1}{n-1}$ to $\frac{n-1}{t-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial

> How does
> $$\frac{\displaystyle\binom{t-2}{n-2}}{\displaystyle\binom{t-1}{n-1}}$$
> reduce to
> $$\frac{n-1}{t-1}$$

I know that the formula for the nCk = $$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

When i unfold given the formula i get

$$\frac{(t-2)!(n-1)!((t-1)-(n-1))!}{(n-2)!((t-2)-(n-2))!(t-1)!}$$
i dont see how this reduces and i know is probably something so simple im just not seeing

Comment: It should be $(t-1-(n-1))!$ not the two terms with !.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the fact that for any positive integer $n$, $n! = n(n-1)!$.  Therefore,
$$(t-1)! = (t-1)(t-2)!,\\
(n-1)! = (n-1)(n-2)!,$$ and so forth.

Comment: i can see the cancellation now but what about the $$\frac{(t-1)(n-1)!}{(t-2)(n-2)!}$$

Comment: @Daniel see the second line of the answer $(n-1)!=(n-1)(n-2)!$. Also your cancellation is incorrect.